# Validate user inputs into a file in Linux

Tags: linux

How can I validate user inputs into a file in a Linux system?

For example, can I prevent users from entering '#' or ';' in /etc/passwd?

Comment: The best way is prevent users edit that file manually if they not know what they do, or make a script to detect thats characters in /etc/passwd or tech users use correct tools as @Sven say

Answer (score 2):

There is no global way to do this, but for some specific files, checks exist.

E.g. you only should edit `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` to enforce correct syntax. For `/etc/passwd`, you can check the syntax with `pwck` after the fact (or write a wrapper that saves into temp files and send those to `pwck` before replacing the original file upon success).

---

Addendum, thanks to @wazoox: `vipw` is `visudo` for `/etc/passwd`. Use it if you are unsure.

Comment: Use "vipw" for /etc/passwd, too.